# How to figure out what template an e-shop is using?

Tags: php, templates, shopping-cart

Hi there fellow programmers,

I am trying to figure out what kind of a template a certain eshop is using. The reason is that the owner of the eshop asked me if I can change the layout, and I am not sure if I could do that based on the template.

I am pretty sure it is NOT a standard CMS (like Joomla, WP etc) with a cart plugin.

Below, I will give you here some parts of the code as seen when viewing the source of the website in the browser, hoping that someone of you has seen sth like that before.

```
<link href="/skins/just/customer/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link href="/skins/just/customer/print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" /> 


<link href="/lib/autocomplete/autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

```
var warning_mark = "&lt;&lt;";

var currencies = {
    'primary': {
        'decimals_separator': '.',
        'thousands_separator': ',',
        'decimals': '2',
        'coefficient': '1.00000'
    },
    'secondary': {
        'decimals_separator': '.',
        'thousands_separator': ',',
        'decimals': '2',
        'coefficient': '1.00000'
    }
};

var cart_language = 'GR';
var images_dir = '/skins/just/customer/images';
var notice_displaying_time = 5;
var cart_prices_w_taxes = false;
var translate_mode = false;
var iframe_urls = new Array();
var iframe_extra = new Array();
var regexp = new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.runCart('C');
});

document.write('<style>.cm-noscript { display:none }</style>'); // hide noscript tags
//]]>






<script type="text/javascript" src="/addons/recurring_billing/js/func.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

// Extend core function
fn_register_hooks('recurring_billing', ['check_exceptions']);

</script>
```

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear they are using CS-Cart: http://www.cs-cart.com/

This is based on searching for common code. In this case, the cm-noscript class in the CSS turned it up. Further looking at their code indicates alot of similarity.